# Detect Office 365 group in Outlook recipient list

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

Is it possible to detect Office 365 Group as email recipient when [iterating over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-set-or-add-recipients#to-get-recipients) email recipient list? [EmailAddressDetails.recipientType](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.MailboxEnums.htm#recipienttype-string) does not have a special value for it. I noticed that the group is of "*other*" `recipientType`, but I wouldn't like to rely just on that.

[image: Office 365 group in Outllok]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now there is no way to do that using Office-js api. You can use graph api to do that. With me/memberOf you can find all the groups in which you are a member, and look up in that list for the interested email.